# Linq to SQL many to many Relationships - Insert Update & Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I have a database that relies on a bunch of Many-to-Many and rather than denormalizing the whole database (which is quite large) I would like to know if there is a SIMPLE way of implementing Many-to-Many Relationships using LINQ-to-SQL Yet...

Everywhere I look I find articles on HOW Difficult It is, or A Simple Workaround that is actually "NOT" Simple. But all the articles I have been able to locate are pretty dated, using asp.net 3.5.

Should I just Create a Stored Procedure and then Drag it into the .DBML file as a method?

So I guess my question is:

Is there any new way to implement many-to-many using Linq-to-Sql in ASP.NET 4.0 along with MVC 3.

---

Examples of usage in my Project:

[image: DBML]

In the finished model, there will be Other Tables linked to the Many-to-Many Tables (i.e. EventAddress, EventUrl, VipAddress, VipPicture, GuestAddress, GuestPhone, GuestEmail, etc...)

So you can see when this would be a pain in the a$$ to denormalize.

Thank you,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to SQL will always map directly to the structure of the database. If your database has all of those junction tables, then they will be in your LINQ to SQL model - period.

Comment: So Linq to SQL will take care of all the Mapping for me?

Comment: If I add an Phone# Field to the Employee Create() how Do I go about saving the Phone# to the [Phone] Table and creating the relationship to the Employee?  Do I have to JOIN the [Phone] Table on Save?

Comment: @Timothy: LINQ to SQL does _no_ mapping. It's a direct copy of the database structure. EF allows you to map.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Entity Framework?
It handles m:n relationships nicely. In your case the EmployeeAddress table would be abstracted away as a list of addresses on your Employee object.
It is also my impression that linq to sql isn't really a priority for Microsoft, EF Is.
I understand if you do not wish to convert an existing project, but for new projects EF4 would probably be a better fit.

Comment: actually I started the project out with EF, I know EF quite well. but I but there are parts of this application that I could not get EF to do at all. So I had to convert it over to Linq-to-SQL for the functionality. I even had a .DBML and a .EDMX in the same project to map differnt classes, but that was just not going to work out.

Comment: but if a new release of EF ever supports it, I will most likely convert the project (if really nessesary).

Comment: @Timothy: what does LINQ to SQL do that EF doesn't do? I've never heard of any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Although you can map many-to-many relationships in both LINQ to SQL
>   and LINQ to Entities, LINQ to Entities allows a direct mapping of
>   many-to-many relationships with no intermediary class, while LINQ to
>   SQL requires that an intermediary class map one-to-many to each of the
>   classes that are party to the many-to-many relationship.

[link to the quote above - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx)